# Counting textarea rows, display, increase, decrease

Tags: javascript, html, rows

I'm trying to count textarea rows using pure javascript and I'm not sure why my `selector.rows` is not return correct number of rows :(
this is my js:

```
var selector = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(i = 0; i < selector.length; i++){
   var array = selector[i];
   var count = array.rows;
   console.log(array, count);
   if(count > 1 &&  count.scrollHeight < count.offsetHeight){
       count--
       console.log(array.rows);
   }else{
       count++
       console.log(array.rows);
   }
}
```

**[jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/qxKmW/45/)**

Comment: It's working in chrome.

Comment: @Grimbode Nope, is not working ...

Comment: Do you want to get the number of rows that the textbox has? or the number of rows that the text inside the textbox occupies? Your code works fine for the first one (returns the value of the attribute `rows` in the textarea)

Comment: You have (at least) one error in that code: the variable `count` is a number, and not an object/element. You cannot apply `scrollHeight` or `offsetHeight` to it, and it will return `undefined` for those values. That will make the condition always go through the `else`. You should be using the `array` variable instead: `array.scrollHeight` and `array.offsetHeight`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I want to count number of rows that exist inside on that textarea of course and not to get value of attribute rows... Ohh I know that error, I eas testing someting on that if/else and forgot to change the variable, however my problem is counting rows  :(

Comment: Good. I found a solution for that, and I'm writing it as an answer. I'll post it shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works fine, because it is designed to return the number of rows that the `textbox` displays (the attribute `rows` of the `textarea`). But you want the number of lines that the text inside the `textarea` occupies, and here is a solution for that:

1. Get the `height` of the textarea (I used `getComputedStyle()` as the height is not defined)
2. Calculate the `line-height` for the content in the `textarea` (= height / rows).
3. Get the `scrollHeight` of the `textarea`.
4. Calculate the number of rows by dividing the `scrollHeight` by the calculated `line-height`.

It would be something like this:

```js
var selector = document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

for(i = 0; i < selector.length; i++){
    
    var txtarea = selector[i];
    var count = txtarea.rows;
    
    // get the textarea height
    var cs = window.getComputedStyle(txtarea, null);
    var tHeight = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue("height"));
  
    // calculate the line-height
    var tLineHeight = tHeight / count;
  
    // calculate the number of rows in the textarea
    var tRows = Math.round(txtarea.scrollHeight / tLineHeight);
  
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML += "ROWS = " + tRows + "<br>";
    
}//end for
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="40">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eam ex bonorum scripserit. Audire diceret delectus ex usu. Sonet alienum duo id. Elit delenit pro ex, quo case honestatis eloquentiam ea, everti detracto intellegat no nam. Pro quodsi euismod qualisque ei. Est et modus porro, eam solet gubergren ea.

In soleat eleifend per, no per nibh mollis labitur. Sit ei possim molestiae, ius antiopam principes ei. Ea eam soleat fierent. Mel et quod veri convenire, vis no modus oporteat posidonium. Dicunt viderer vocibus his te, qui agam iriure pertinacia te. In sit homero facilisi iudicabit. Timeam eligendi sed an.


</textarea>

<textarea rows="4" cols="40">
 Hello
</textarea>

<div id="results"></div>
```

And you can also see it in a variation of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxKmW/46/ (in this case, check the console log)

---

One *issue* with this solution: it will return the higher value of these two:

- The number of rows of the content inside the `textarea`; or
- The number of rows defined in the `rows` attribute (or its default value).

That's why in the example above will return 4 instead of 2 for the second `textarea`. A possible solution for this would be to set the `rows` attribute to 1, then you'll always get the correct value.

Comment: I added the `Math.round()` to get rid of the incorrect decimals that are calculated in the code above (the JSFiddle example doesn't have it, and it gets a round number without it)